# How to calculate relative percent to total?

Tags: javascript, html, math, svelte

I'm trying to create a word-cloud with font-size based on percent of total. Each word has a "count" attribute.

```
<h2>Cryptos</h2>
<div class="topics">
{#each cryptos as topic}
    <a
    href="/cryptos/{topic._id}"
    style="font-size: {(topic.count / topics[0].count) * 100 + 100}%;">${topic._id}
    ({topic.count})</a>
{/each}
</div>
```

This isn't quite working correctly and I'm not sure why.

```
font-size: {(topic.count / topics[0].count) * 100 + 100}%;
```

The topics are sorted in descending order based on `.count`

I basically want the font-size to be 100% at the low end and 200% at the high end.

Comment: What `font-size` values are being generated by your code?

Comment: Seems right on the surface. What exactly does "isn't quite working correctly" mean in this case?

Comment: i get one large one and all others are the same size.

Comment: `font-size: 107.xxx%` for most tags.

Comment: @chovy how many words/counts are there? Because if there are 14 words and each has a count of 1, then ```107.xx%``` seems correct.

Comment: something is off: you can see at https://briskreader.com/topics the max should be 200% and the min should be 100%

Comment: could it be that you are comparing the values of `cryptos` with he first one of `topics` ? if so the values themselves look correct to me (biggest topic is 98)

Comment: shoot. you might be right. my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font size can be varied by comparing the range of font sizes with the range of word counts.

Imagine you have a list of words and their count:

```js
const words = [
  { text: "apples", count: 10 },
  { text: "pears", count: 30 },
  // ...
]
```

The range of `font-size` can be computed:

```js
const minFontSize = 10
const maxFontSize = 30

// delta between sizes
const fontRange = maxFontSize - minFontSize
```

Then compute the min word count, max word count and the range of word count. Reactive statements work well for this:

```js
// list of counts
$: counts = words.map(record => record.count)

// minimum word count
$: min = Math.min(...counts)

// maximum word count
$: max = Math.max(...counts)

// delta between smallest and largest word count
$: countRange = max - min
```

Now we can compute the font size:

```
minFontSize + (deltaWordCount * sizeRatio)
```

or more specifically:

```
{#each words as word}
  <span style="font-size: {minFontSize + ((word.count - min) * (fontRange / countRange))}px">
    {word.text}
  </span>
{/each}
```

You can find a working example here: https://svelte.dev/repl/770e4a35186449a182b8edecc4ed88ba?version=3.31.0